# where to place onBackPressed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, back-button, back

I tried to configure the Back button with the:

```
Public void onBackPressed(){return;}
```

But it doesn't makes anything (I also tried with the super.onBack... and with the finish). My app is a amateur app based on: Onclik the X button: "english" so it shows you the english activity. And 100 more activities.

```
    package com.example.speakcat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void english(View view)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_english);
    }
```

The onBackPressed is well placed? Because here it doesn't make anything.
I hope you can help me, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must overrid the method with the `super` calling. That's all you need to do if your idea is return to he previous `Activity`.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but is not working, I place it right? I just updated my question to show my current code.

Answer (score 0):

finish your current activity, will automatically go the previous one

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    finish();
}
```

Comment: It closes the app. I think that is because it considers that there is only one activity. The first time I run the app there were all the activities on the app menu. Then I read here to delete all the activities from the androidmanifest, and now I have only the Mainactivity. How Can I put one activity inside another?

Comment: create another activity, then register in Manifest.

Comment: Yes, but on the manifest, all are on parallel, and I tried to put an activity inside Mainactivity <activity and it shows me an error. 
The thing is that when the activity finishes it goes to the app menu, is there any other solution?

Comment: due to your edited code, means that you want a button that has an event, when click on it, it go to the next Activity, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Log.d("CDA", "onKeyDown Called");
       onBackPressed();
      return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);//goto whichever activity you want by clearing top of stack.
    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);// clear top of stack
    startActivity(myIntent);
    finish();
    return;
 }
```

You can call finish if you want to go back to previous activity.
If you have Actvity A and you navigate to B. A goes to background. Its on activity stack. On finish in Activity B pops out of the stack and activity A comes to foreground. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html. Have a look and this link.

Comment: Ok, I understood the Task and stack stuff, but if I use your code it shows me 3 errors, two with the keyeveny (I created a class, but nothing). I have seen your code with old versions, I'm using 4.0 it should work??